# Expected length of 2-coin tossing game until player's ruin

Tags: probability, recurrence-relations, expectation

Player $A$ and player $B$ are playing coin tossing game. Player $A$ has $n$ coins, player B has $m$ coins. If two head or tails turn up then player $A$ takes both coins. Otherwise player $B$ takes them.

I'm thinking this way:

Let us define $F_{n,m}$ - expected game length if $A$ has $n$ coins and $B$ has $m$.
Probability of winning in a single round for both players is equal.

Then one has
$$F_{n,m} = 1 + 1/2F_{n-1,m} + 1/2 F_{n,m-1}$$

Obviously $F_{0, m} = 0$ and $F_{n,0} = 0$.

How do I solve this reccurence relation? Or should I went differently about this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X_t$ be the number of coins player $A$ has at time $t$. Then $0\leqslant X_t\leqslant n+m$ a.s. so $X_t$ is integrable, and $$\mathbb E[X_{t+1}\mid \mathcal F_t] = \frac12(X_t+1)+\frac12(X_t-1)=X_t, $$so $\{X_t\}$ is a martingale. Let $$\tau = \inf\{t>0:X_t\in\{0,n+m\}\}. $$ Since $\tau$ is the absorption time of a birth-death Markov chain with finitely many states, $\mathbb E[\tau]<\infty$. Moreover, we have $$\mathbb E[|X_{t+1}-X_t|\mid\mathcal F_t]\leqslant 1, $$ and so by optional stopping, $$\mathbb E[X_\tau] = \mathbb E[X_0]. $$ It follows that $$\mathbb E[X_\tau\mid X_\tau=0]\mathbb P(X_\tau=0)+\mathbb E[X_\tau\mid X_\tau=n+m]\mathbb P(X_\tau=n+m)=n, $$
from which the probability of player A winning is
$$
p_A:=\mathbb P(X_\tau=n+m) = \frac n{n+m}.
$$

Let $W_t$ denote the winnings of player $A$ at time $t$. Then $$X_t = X_0 + \sum_{i=1}^t W_i, $$ and where the $W_i$ are i.i.d. with $$\mathbb P(W_1=1)=\mathbb P(W_1=-1)=\frac12. $$  Since $\mathbb E[W_1]=0$ and $\mathbb E[W_1^2]=1$, Wald's second identity yields
$$\mathbb E\left[\left(\sum_{t=1}^\tau W_t\right)^2\right] = \mathbb E[\tau].$$
Since $$\sum_{t=1}^\tau W_t = X_t-X_0, $$ it follows that
\begin{align}
\mathbb E[\tau] &= \mathbb E[(X_\tau-X_0)^2]\\
&= \mathbb E[(X_\tau-X_0)^2\mid X_\tau=0]\mathbb P(X_\tau=0)+E[(X_\tau-X_0)^2\mid X_\tau=n+m]\mathbb P(X_\tau=n+m)\\
&= (0-n)^2(1-p_a) + (n+m-n)^2p_a\\
&= \frac{n^2m}{n+m} + \frac{nm^2}{n+m}\\
&= nm.
\end{align}
Intuitively this makes sense because for a given $N=n+m$, the expected length is maximized when $n=m$ (for even $N$) or $|n-m|=1$ (for odd $N$).

Answer (score 2):

Its just a non-homogeneous linear recurrence. You can solve it by generating functions or whatever.

Alternatively, you can model it as a MC on state space {0,...,n+m} (with the state being the number of coins A has) and look at the expected hitting time of the set {0,n+m}. The transition matrix of this MC will be $i\to i+1$ with probability 1/2 and $i\to i-1$ with probability 1/2 for $i \neq 0,n+m$ and $0\to 0$ with probability $1$ and $n+m \to n+m$ with probability $1$. You can then set up the equivalent system of equations for expected hitting times as in Theorem 1.3.5 in Norris' Markov Chains (linked [here](http://www.statslab.cam.ac.uk/~james/Markov/s13.pdf)), which says that the expected hitting time of set $A$ starting from state $i$ is zero if $i \in A$, and is given by $1+ \sum_{j \notin A} p_{ij} (\text{ hitting time starting from state j to A})$ and $p_{ij}$ is the probability of $i \to j$'s minimal non-negative solution for the hitting times.

Comment: It is the classical problem of the [gambler's ruin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambler's_ruin)

Comment: It is a gambler's ruin problem, but the most common usage of gambler's ruin is to consider a MC on state space $\mathbb{N} \cup \{0\}$ with transition probabilities $i \to i+1$ to be $p$ (typically $1/2$) and $i \to i - 1$ to be $1-p$ for $i \in \mathbb{N}$ and $0 \to 0 = 1$, and study the hitting time of $\{0\}$, which is slightly different.

Comment: You are right. I mentioned the term "gambler's ruin" as being a keyword that might help for further researches around this subject.